# How to Prompt user to enter Card holder name in CardIOActivity

Tags: card.io

I know that currently card.io SDK doesn't scan Card Holder name or zip code. However we can pass 'EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE' in Intent so that Card.io prompts user to enter Postal code before onActivityResult is called.

Is something similar possible for prompting user to enter Card Holder name? I can do that if I have to, by calling another Activity probably. However if this can be directly handled by card.io then that will be easier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, card.io does not offer a user name entry screen at this time.